# Is "This story can be true." grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

I want to ask a question about the usage of an auxiliary verb "can."

I think the next sentence is grammatically incorrect.

> This story can be true.

In contrast, I think the next sentence is correct.

> This story could[might/may] be true.

Is my understanding right?

`supplementary explanation`

In a dictionary, I learned about "can" that expresses possibility (not ability or permission) as follows:

---

In **positive** sentences, "can" expresses **general** possibility, that is, possibility that a thing happens **irregularly several times**, and "can" isn't able to express **specific** possibility, that is, possibility that a thing happens **specifically only once**.

For example, the next sentence is **not** correct.

> It can rain tomorrow.

In contrast, the following sentence is correct.

> It may rain tomorrow.

(I think not only "may" but also "could"/"might" are correct.)

---

That's why I thought "This story can be true" is **not** correct. For possibility that this story is true is **specific**, that is, it happens **specifically only once**.

Comment: They're all *grammatical*. It's just that the ***can*** version is an incredibly unlikely utterance compared to the others, because *semantically* it wouldn't normally make sense in most contexts. It's just about possible to imagine someone who's not very good at maths saying **2 plus 2 could / might / may be 4** (I can certainly imagine ***The square root of 132365569809 could / might / may be an integer***). But it's almost impossible to imagine a context where someone could validly say **2 plus 2 can be 4**, even though it's ***syntactically*** fine.

Comment: I made a supplementary explanation. I'd appreciate it if you would read it.

Comment: I don't think "specifically only once" is meaningful here, but you're quite right that utterances like ***This story can be true*** and ***It can rain tomorrow*** are essentially "incorrect" (except in *very* unusual contexts that are hardly worth bothering about, since they will probably never arise). Note that whereas I can say to you *Pick a card. It **can** be red or black* (because ***there is still a choice in play***), I CAN'T say *Now let's talk about that card you just picked, which **can** be red or black*. Because there's no longer a choice it has to be ***could / may / might be***.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect. All of the following sentences are correct:

> "This story can be true"
>
> "This story could be true"
>
> "This story might be true"
>
> "This story may be true"

To me, can and could imply possibility, whereas may and might implies a slim possibility, (e.g. "it might, if all goes well"). Also, to me, can implies that certain conditions have to be true, for example "this story can be true if you make a small donation"

Comment: You mean "Your understanding is *incorrect*" because the OP claims that "This story can be true" is not good grammar.

Comment: wait.. i completely missed the grammatically incorrect bit there sorry

Answer (score 1):

"This story may/might be true" is simple and common. It expresses a possibility, or uncertainty. The speaker does not know if the story is true or not.

"This story can be true" is grammatically correct, but less common.  We often use "can" when something is potential.  When the speaker is able to do something.  So this would be used when one is able to make the story true.  That is possible in the following context.

> Teacher: I want you to write an essay about your favourite story. This story can be a fairytale, or a modern story, or this story can be true.  You can choose the story.

We also use "can" to express greater confidence than "might":

> When my uncle told me that bigfoot had taken his picnic, I didn't believe him.  But when I saw the footprints and saw the photos my uncle had taken I realised that his story can be true!

It is less common than "might be true" but it is grammatically correct and sometimes idiomatic.

However, usually "might be true", "may be true", "is likely to be true", "is probably true" are better ways to express a range of doubt

Comment: In your "teacher" example, ***can*** essentially modifies ***choose*** (or equivalent) even if that verb isn't explicitly specified. If the teacher had started by saying *We're going to study a short story written by X*, it wouldn't normally be possible to continue with *This story can be true*, even if the teacher doesn't know whether it's true or not. He could certainly say *It could / might / may be true* to reflect ***uncertainty*** in that situation - but not ***can***, which reflects ***ability to change / make a choice*** (meaningless where "objective truth" inherently applies).

Comment: IMO, the "can" In "I realized that his story can be true!" sounds a bit awkward.  "Could" sounds a bit more natural.

Comment: Does "can" express greater confidence than "might"? I first heard such an explanation. Also, I learned "could" expresses **less** great confidence than "might". You mean "can" and "could" express almost the same meaning as "must"? For example, does the next sentence have almost the same meaning even if must is replaced with can / could? "He must  be clever since he solved the difficult problem."

Comment: (from wikipedia) *I can speak English* means "I am able to speak English" or "I know how to speak English."
*You can smoke here* means "you may (are permitted to) smoke here" .....
*There can be strong rivalry between siblings* means that such rivalry is possible......