# Can I use "Could" for advice?

Tags: difference, usage

You can use my pen

You could use my pen

What's the difference? Can we use could for advice?

Comment: also related: [Is "This story can be true." grammatically incorrect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283635/) and [General past possibility with 'could'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198414/general-past-possibility-with-could)

Answer (score 1):

If someone asks you if you can use your pen, you would probably reply

> Yes, you can use my pen

and not

> Yes, you could use my pen

As using "could" implies that you **might or might not** give the person your pen, while "can" implies that they **can** use your pen

Definition of could for reference:

> could: used to indicate possibility

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to use *could* for a suggestion, which is a kind of advice.

> You could take the train.

> You could use a hammer.

In the case of *you could use my pen* it could also be about giving permission, and it might be ambiguous whether it is permission or suggestion: usually the tone of voice will make that clear.